# Redefine form client area

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In WinForms I want to create a class that inherits from form and shows a custom painted title header area at the top. Now it would be nice to redefine the client area of the form, so coordinate 0,0 is at the bottom left corner of the header.
I read that this cannot be done but I wonder if that is true. Also the information I found was quite sparse, and mostly about drawing outside the client area and not about redefining it.

As a workaround I could of course create a PointToFormPoint function that translates the coordinates according to the header, but this would just be a workaround.

Is the clientarea so deeply coupled to the WinForms framework that it really cannot be programmatically changed?

Comment: It is deeply coupled to the way Windows works.  You certainly *can* change the client area, you have to handle the WM_NCCALCSIZE message in an override for WndProc().  It is unpleasant.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that but I guess it's not worth it to implement a bunch of unknown deathtraps for some added comfort in this application. Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  The simplest way to do this is to just add a Panel below the header.  That gives you a new coordinate system that starts at (0, 0) where you want it, the panel's client area.

Comment: That's true but the implementation of the panel as the main control bucket in the Visual Studio designer gave me a hard time before with a derived control. But I'll try this and see how it works in the Form. But a good suggestion.